# How to create an if statement in javascript that will run if a variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)

Would it be like this?

```
if(variable == undefined) {
```

or would it be like this?

```
if(variable == "undefined") {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (typeof variable == 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if(typeof(variable) == 'undefined')
```

Comment: You don’t need the parentheses as `typeof` is an operator and not a function.

Comment: @chromedude See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator

Comment: ya you are right Gumbo... sorry about that :) was in a hurry when i answered :P

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) here, like this:

```
if(typeof variable == "undefined") {
```

Comment: Why would you add an extra call to `typeof` when simply checking `variable == undefined` works?

Comment: @Justin - `undefined` may be redefined, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gHjg5/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(variable == undefined) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
if (variable == undefined) {}
```